# Is using "get on developing" correct in this phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, gerunds

> You could get on developing this project and help me to add more features to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use

> You could **go** on developing this project and help me **add** more
>   features to it.

or (as @BarrieEngland suggested)

> You could get on **with** developing this project and help me **with adding** more
>   features to it.

But I do believe that they are all technically valid.

Answer (score 1):

It might be heard, but *get on **with*** is perhaps more usual.

Comment: so the correct phrase is: "you could get on with developing this project and help me to add more features to that" ?

Comment: I don't say that one is more 'correct' than the other. I just say that you're more likely to find _get on with_. If you're a foreign learner, that's the construction you should use, but bear in mind that it is colloquial.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could get on developing this project
2. and help me to add more features to that.

The second part seems to suggest that the *get on* phrase is used in the sense *get/ come on board*.

*You could **join** this team developing the project and help me to add more features to it.*
 Or
*You could **join** us in developing the project and help me to add more features to it.*

Comment: but there is not any team. there is a project that i created and want to say that others can work on that.

Comment: That should be no issue. The sentence I provided is an example, only to show the meaning. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're tring to say is "Help me add more features to the application (?) by joining the development team."

Answer (score -1):

Sounds rather colloquial to me. There is a preposition missing and "to get on with" is usually followed by a noun, whereas to continue, which can be used as a synonym, can be followed by the gerund.

get on with the development of this project...

continue developing this project

I'm not sure the end of the sentence is very idiomatic, is "that" the project? If so, I would use "it" instead of "that"

Comment: yes, "that" is "the project".